# Meaning of 閒日 (cantonese)

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence 唔知佢點解，佢閒日唔會打電話嚟。

What is the meaning of 閒日？
The official translation given by my reference is “weekdays”, but when i searched this in the dictionary, the meaning given is “free time”.

Which is it? Is it a cultural difference?

Comment: 閒日 means weekdays, but contextually it's a metaphor(free time/non-busy days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words.hk defines it as:

> 名詞
>   星期一至五, 唔屬於星期六日或公眾假期嘅日子（量詞：個）
>   weekdays: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday, Thursday or Friday; usually with the restriction of a non-holiday

And they give the example:

> 閒日飲茶有折喎！
>   haan4 jat2 jam2 caa4 jau5 zit3 wo3!
>   Discount for dim-sum on weekdays!

——

閒日 is literally made up of the characters for idle + day. Why weekdays are idle days could only be explained by slow business - because business is would, assumably, be good on the weekends and holidays. But you’d never hear this usage in Mandarin where it just simply means “off day,” i.e.: a day where one doesn’t work.

——

Guangzhouhua-Putonghua gives it a different Cantonese definition:

> 背集；不逢集的日子。

“Non-market days.”

CCCanto’s definition is also similar:

> free time or off day

Answer (score 2):

閒日 means "weekdays" instead of "weekend" because restaurants, touring  and entertaining business get busy in weekend and holiday.  (I worked in restaurants, so I am familiar with this term)

閒日(weekdays/non-busy days) is a lingo in the business mentioned above.

The more accurate translation of 閒日 should be "non-holiday weekdays" or literally "non-busy day"

Another Cantonese term for weekdays is "拜頭" (short for 禮拜頭). "拜尾" (short for 禮拜尾) means weekend.